# How can I check whether a function is a function type in python?

Tags: python, types

How can I check whether a function is a function type in python?

I did this:

```
print(type(func_1))
```

python tells me that this is a
`<class 'function'>`

However, when I did this:

```
print(type(func_1) is function)
```

I got a NameError
`NameError: name 'function' is not defined`

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't do this check at all - there are other types of callable objects in Python than functions, why would you arbitrarily prevent their use?

Answer (score -2):

you could compare it to the type of a lambda function (same thing)

```py
print(type(func_1) == type(lambda:None))
```